# Setting a flag in C as elegantly as in assemby language

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, flags

Flags handling in C feels cumbersome, compared to assembly.

I am looking for a way to make the C code as readable as assembly.

In Assembly:

```
#define powerOn flagsByte,0
... 
bsf powerOn ; Turn on the power
bcf powerOn ; Turn off the power
btfsc powerOn ; If the power is on...
```

In C:

```
flagsByte |= (1 << 0) ; // Turn on the power
flagsByte &= ~(1 << 0) ; // Turn off the power
if (flagsByte & (1 << 0)); // If the power is on...
```

In C, with a macro:

```
#define BIT_SET(var,bitNo) (var |= (1<<(bitNo)))
BIT_SET(flagsByte,0) ; // Turn on the power
```

That works, but it's still not as clean as in assembly.

I'd love to do:

```
#define powerOn flagsByte,0
BIT_SET(powerOn) ; // Turn on the power
```

But that doesn't work, because it expands to:

```
flagsByte,0 |= (1<<())
```

instead of:

```
flagsByte |= (1<<(0))
```

Question:

Is there an elegant way in C to set, clear or test a flag that is defined as follows?

```
#define powerOn flagsByte,0
```

Comment: I'm not sure hiding the target variable or register for "elegance" scales when there are hundreds of registers exposed by the CPU and peripherals.  E.g., consider a `reset` bit.  Is that `reset` for the wifi chip?  The AES encryption engine?  The tx data path?  The rx data path?  The DCM clock? The serial port?  The watchdog?  The CPU?  And so on.

Comment: I believe that CLR(serRxInterFlg ) (with a #define serRxInterFlg PIF1,U1RxIF, somewhere else) is far more readable than PIF1 &= !(1<<U1RxIF). I would not call a flag simply "reset".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I prefer the bit-field syntax, and without macros since my flags are almost always inside structs anyway. However, if you insist on writing assembler in C, here's how:

```
/* We need to indirect the macro call so that the pair of arguments get expanded */
#define BITSET_(f,i) do{f|= 1<<(i);}while(0)
#define BITCLR_(f,i) do{f&=~(1<<(i));}while(0)
#define BITCHK_(f,i) ((f)&(1<<(i)))

#define BITSET(fi) BITSET_(fi)
#define BITCLR(fi) BITCLR_(fi)
#define BITCHK(fi) BITCHK_(fi)

/* Define the flag container and bit number as per OP */
#define poweron flags1,0
#define warnuser flags7,4

/* Sample uses */
BITSET(poweron);
BITCLR(warnuser);
/* Since BITCHK expands to a parenthesized expression, I can get away with
 * leaving out the parentheses in the if statement. Not saying that's a good
 * idea or anything.
 */
if BITCHK(poweron) BITSET(warnuser);
```

If you have gcc, you can verify this with `gcc -E flag_macros.c`

Comment: Great! That will do it. Your approach appears to be the same as the one from jthill, right? That is, the trick is to do two macro expansions.

Comment: @DavideAndrea: Apparently so. I didn't see his answer.

Comment: Well, @rici, yours came first, so I flagged it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a set of macros closely matching your assembly example:

```
#define powerOn        0
#define someotherfield 1

#define BITMASK(field) (1u << (field))
#define SET(field)  do { flagsByte |= BITMASK(field); } while(0)
#define CLR(field)  do { flagsByte &= ~BITMASK(field); } while(0)
#define TEST(field) (flagsByte & BITMASK(field))

/* Use examples */
SET(powerOn);
CLEAR(powerOn);
if (TEST(powerOn)) {
    // Danger!
}
```

Here's a variant that allows you to include the variable in the particular field definition. It's a bit tricky as it involves [argument prescan](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan)

```
#define powerOn        flagsByte,0                                                                                                                                                      
#define someotherfield flagsByte,1                                                                                                                                                      

#define BITMASK(field) (1u << (field))                                                                                                                                                  
#define _SET(var, field)  do { var |= BITMASK(field); } while(0)                                                                                                                        
#define SET(x) _SET(x)

/* Use examples */                                                                                                                                                                      
SET(powerOn);
```

Comment: With your approach, I would need 3 separate macros for every variable whose bits I want to manipulate. That includes all sorts of Special Function Registers, in addition to various bytes of flags. That would be dozens of macros. I would not look forward to that.

Comment: I do like your "BITMASK(field) (1u << (field))" macro, though. I think I'll use it. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a variant of the macro that allows using variable name in the field definition. It's borders on preprocessor abuse, though, IMHO.

Comment: I checked your update, and, yes, it now does answer my question completely; thanks. I see that you're using the same solution that jthill and rici gave: 2 macro expansions.

Answer (score 2):

You could `#define powerOn flagsByte |= (1 << 0);` and then just use it like a statement. As in

```
// do stuff...
powerOn; // Turn power on.
// do stuff...
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. But I have dozens of flags, and I can't really imagine writing dozens of macros, three macros (one to set it, one to clear it, one to test it) for each flag.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know. ArtemB seems to have an elegant solution that would work for that.

Answer (score 2):

With GCC you can define so-called *bit fields* and manipulate them like struct members:

```
struct flagsByte
  {
    unsigned int powerOn: 1;  /* single bit */
  };

flagsByte.powerOn = 0;
flagsByte.powerOn = 1;
```

Building upon this, it is possibile to define a couple of trivial macros, reminiscent of Assembly:

```
#define bsf(X) flagsByte.(X) = 1
#define bcf(X) flagsByte.(X) = 0
```

and simply write

```
bsf(powerOn);  /* set flag   */
bcf(powerOn);  /* clear flag */
```

Unfortunately, this is not applicable to every C compiler.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't quite answer my question, which assumes #define powerOn flagsByte,0.  In your solution, "flagsByte.powerOn" does include the word "flagsByte", which is less elegant than assembly. Still, very nice, thank you.

Comment: bit fields are not a gcc extension. They are part of standard C, so they should be available on any conformant compiler.

Comment: "#define bsf(X) flagsByte.(X) = 1" means that I need a separate macro for every variable whose bits I want to manipulate. That includes all sorts of Special Function Registers, in addition to various bytes of flags. I would not look forward to that.

Comment: "struct flagsByte" would work for flag bytes, which I would define as I need them. But would not work for Special Function Registers, which are already defined by the processor files included in the project.

Comment: If you want to set many bits in many registers (as you said in a comment on ArtemB's answer), you will inevitably have to refer to both the register/variable and the bit you want to set.

Answer (score 2):

You do this with a second expansion.

```
~/sandbox/20$ cat >t.c
#define BITSET_INNER(a,b) a |= (1<<b)
#define BITSET(spec) BITSET_INNER(spec)
#define f1 flagword,3

    BITSET(f1)

~/sandbox/20$ cc -E t.c
# 1 "t.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "t.c"




    flagword |= (1<<3)
```

Add token pasting and a with a strong gorge you can get some extremely gratifying results out of the C preprocessor.

Comment: Wow! I thank you! Your approach appears to be the same as the one from rici, right?

Comment: De nada, hf, and thanks back atcha :-)  Boosted my mood. (edit: yup.)

Answer (score 1):

You could just define some constants, not using the preprocessor but enums for fewer surprises:

```
enum flags{
    powerOn = 1<<0,
    powerMask = ~powerOn,
    /*...*/
};
```

And use them like this:

```
flagsByte |= power;
flagsByte &= ~power;
flagsByte &= powerMask; /* same as previous line */
```

A good rule of thumb in C (and C++): Do not use the preprocessor if you can avoid it.

Anyway, if you can live with the inherent implementation-definedness of bitfields, use bitfields as Roberto Reale proposes.

Comment: I see that your solution is more elegant that the standard C solution, though maybe not quite as elegant as assembly. I do thank you.